# Making sure all http requests go through my nginx api gateway

Tags: nginx, jwt, authorization, client-certificates, api-gateway

I am designing an nginx based API Gateway that includes some authentication & authorization middleware inside, and I am not sure how to enforce requests to go through the APIGW.

So the apigw will receive HTTP requests with a JWT that was generated by the user. if the JWT is valid, I want to verify that the user is allowed to access the API (via ip blacklisting, client agent blacklisting and user permissions), and if so proxy the request to the backend server and add the jwt authorization header to the request send to the backend server.

My problem is that in my current network design (which is not under my control) I cannot block users from accessing the backend servers directly without going through the apigw.

So my question is: **How can I make sure that the http requests that the backend server receives are only from the api gateway?**

I have several solutions, but I want to keep the solution as simple as possible & would like some input on these ideas:

1. On the backend application I can whitelist requests the originate only from the apigw ip address.
   The problem with this is that my apigw does not have a static ip address
2. I can add a client certificate to the apigw, and authenticate to the backend application that the request actually came from the apigw.
   The problem with this is that the backend must be accessible using ssl / tls which I don't want to setup, and the backend application must add some extra logic to authenticate the client certificate
3. I can add an authentication header similar to the amazon s3 authentication that signs the request + timestamp.
   This is seems like a pretty good option, but it also requires the backend to verify this signature in addition to verifying the jwt that came with the request.
   Also the AWS token & the JWT are both sent using the authorization header, so I would have to send the AWS token on an alternative custom header (i.e. "Authorization2")
4. I can take the JWT sent by the user & resign it using an additional private key only known to the APIGW. When the backend application verifies the JWT, it will use the public key provided by the apigw (and not the original public key).

So far I am most in favor of solution number 4 of resigning the JWT because:

- It does not require any extra logic on the backend application, because it already verifies the JWT. It only has to change the public key to the one of the APIGW.
- This allows me to inject extra properties about the user into the JWT (like extra permissions gathered from another source)
- This allows me to shorten the expiration time of the token in order to avoid replay attacks. The clients JWT can still have a normal expiration time (for example 1 hour), but every JWT sent to the backend server can have an expiration time of 60 seconds from the time the request was sent. In this way requests can only be replayed a max of 60 seconds after the original request.

So what is your opinion about this? I know that there is no right answer, but what solution do you think will work the best?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do in number 4 is in fact [Token Exchange](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8693) but you will use your API GW as the Authorization Server which performs the exchange. It does seem like a fair option to achieve what you need. Another option might be embedding tokens - your GW can issue a new access token and embed the original inside of it. Then you still allow your backend to operate on the original token sent to the API GW, but accept only requests with tokens wrapped in a JWT issued by the GW. You can have a look at a [Token Sharing Approaches](https://curity.io/resources/learn/token-sharing/) article I wrote to learn more about those techniques.

Comment: Grate article! I'm definitely going to implement a token exchange in my api gateway.